# CSS animate: span rotating

Tags: css, animation, rotation

I'm totally stuck with this example of rotating span. http://jsfiddle.net/C94b8/1/ . What I want to do is rotate spin containing val from input but I just can't make it possible. Also tried changing span to `display: inline-block`. Didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set display to inline-block.
Also, Chrome doesn't support a un-prefixed transform yet. Instead, you need to use `-webkit-transform`. Firefox supports everything, so you don't have to worry there.

Also, you don't have to use `0%` and `100%`. If that's all you're using, you can use `from` and `to`.

One more thing: I think it's IE that doesn't support `rotate`. They want `rotateZ`. So I've changed it.

The finished product?

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform: rotateZ(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotateZ(360deg);}
}

header span {        
    display: inline-block;
    /* All the rest of header span {} code goes here. I didn't copy it all. */
}
```